# How can i add the layout and menu folders in android studio?

Tags: android-studio, layout, menu

i can't found the layout and menu folders in res ??!!there is only "drawable mipmap and values"
SO How can i add the layout and menu folders  in android studio?
thank you.

Answer (score 2):

1- Right click on "res"

2- Select "new" -> "android ressource file"

3- file name (name it)

4- ressources type : select "layout"

5- Hit "ok"
the same for menu folder